# Calling Helper Within If Block in Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, client-templates

I am working with Handlebars.js template engine and am trying to figure out a way to do something like this (contrived example):

```
{{#if itemSelected "SomeItem"}}
    <div>This was selected</div>
{{/if}
```

where `itemSelected` is a registered helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("itemSelected", function(item) {
    var selected = false;
    // Lots of logic that determines if item is selected
    return selected;
});
```

I get errors when trying to use this syntax for the template, and I cannot find any example showing this kind of thing. I do see simple #if blocks like this...

```
{{#if myValueInContext}}
    <div>This will show if myValueInContext results in a truthy value.</div>
{{/if}}
```

But, I can't figure out how to tackle the first example. Maybe I am approaching this wrong.

By the way, I tagged this Mustache as I could not add a Handlebars tag to the question.

Comment: Fixed your tag by removing mustache and adding handlebars.js

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work. If I understand the handlebars documentation correct, the #if is a registered block-helper itself and does not take another registered helper as an argument.

According to the documentation you might implement it like that

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifItemSelected', function(item, block) {
  var selected = false;
  // lots of logic that determines if item is selected

  if(selected) {
    return block(this);
  }
});
```

Afterwards you should be able to call it with

```
{{#ifItemSelected SomeItem}}
    This was selected
{{/ifItemSelected}
```

but you have to make sure *SomeItem* has the proper format. I don't see a way to use a registered handler as conditional in an if-statement.

Comment: @gnowoel's answer might be a better fit for modern Handlebars

Comment: The answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/31010113/2036529 is better

Answer (score 117):

You should add parentheses around the embedded helper invocation:

```
{{#if (itemSelected "SomeItem")}}
    <div>This was selected</div>
{{/if}
```

I did experiments and verified that it just works.

Not sure if it's mentioned in the Handlebars documentation. I learned the trick from the examples of [handlebars-layouts](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/handlebars-layouts#conditional-blocks).

Comment: Yep, this is a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions). It's officially supported, so this is the simplest approach.

Comment: I spent an hour looking for this.. Handlebars v1.3 (yes legacy app): 
`{{#if myBooleanHelper}}` doesn't work. Had to add parenthesis to make it go :-/

Answer (score 43):

With last version (1.0.rc.1) of Handlebars, you have to write sth like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifItemSelected', function(item, options) {
  var selected = false;
  // lots of logic that determines if item is selected

  if (selected) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
});
```

ie. *block(this)* is replaced by **options.fn(this)**

http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals

Comment: As of the latest Handlebars version, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have an else option too, you will need this code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifItemSelected', function(item, options) {
  var selected = false;
  // lots of logic that determines if item is selected

  if (selected) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  else {
   return options.inverse(this);
 }
});
```

Used with:

```
{{#ifItemSelected SomeItem}}
    This was selected
{{else}}
    This was not selected
{{/ifItemSelected}
```