# Conditional "if statement" helper for Handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I am trying to write a conditional if statement helper for Handlebars.js. Essentially, I want to put an "active" class on a link if it is the `Apply Now` page.

Helper:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('isApplyNow', function(block) {
    if(this.title == "Apply Now") {
      return block(this);
    } else {
      return block.inverse(this);
    }
  });
```

And Template:

```
  <ul>
    {{#each pages}}
      <li>
        {{#isApplyNow}}
          <a href="{{url}}" class ='active'>{{this.title}}</a>
        {{else}}
          <a href="{{url}}">{{this.title}}</a>
        {{/if}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}  
  </ul>
```

But, I am getting a very bare-bones javascript error:

```
Uncaught [object Object] in handlebars-1.0.0.beta.2.js:595
```

Can anyone see if I am writing this improperly?

Thanks!

Referenced articles:

[Calling Helper Within If Block in Handlebars Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319231/calling-helper-within-if-block-in-handlebars-template)

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I do see one minor syntax mistake which I believe could be the issue. If you are going to use a helper that takes a block, then you have to close it with the helper name. See how I've replaced your `{{/if}}` with `{{/isApplyNow}}`, like so:

```
    {{#isApplyNow}}
      <a href="{{url}}" class ='active'>{{this.title}}</a>
    {{else}}
      <a href="{{url}}">{{this.title}}</a>
    {{/isApplyNow}}
```

Comment: Ahh duh, I'll try this in a little bit when I get back to that side of the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:
block(this) in the helper will not work anymore. Instead, use block.fn(this)

e.g.

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('isApplyNow', function(block) {
    if (this.title === "Apply Now") 
      return block.fn(this);
    else 
      return block.inverse(this);
 });
```