# Handlebars.js each helper with if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am using the below helper to iterate through a JSON array and return a result based on the condition to find whether an Account is closed or not (`OpenOrClosedDesc=='Closed'`). I am getting all of the Accounts that are closed. But now I want to print an error message on the screen if there are no Closed Accounts.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_Closed', function(list, opts) {
                var i, result = '';
                try {
                    //console.log("List Closed length "+ list.length)
                    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                        if (list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed'){
                          //  console.log("List Closed  "+ list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed')
                            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
                        }
                return result;
            }catch(e){

            }
        });
```

HTML Code :

```
<div id = "Revolving_ClosedAcc">
   {{#repData}}
     {{#each_Closed arf.TradeLine.TradeLine.[Revolving Accounts]}}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {{/each_Closed}}
  {{/repData}}
</div>
```

EDIT Explanation for possible duplicate: 
I tried to return the error message from an else branch but it did not give accurate results. It simply shows there are no closed accounts if it finds one of the accounts is closed. It doesn't go through the for loop. The for loop is the main path as I want to iterate through the whole object array.

EDIT for having count of each account:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_Closed', function(list, opts) {
                var i, result = '',resCounter=0,closedAccountFound = false;
                try {
                    //console.log("List Closed length "+ list.length)
                    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        if (list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed') {
                            // console.log("List Closed  "+ list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed')
                            result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
                            resCounter++;
                            closedAccountFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(resCounter);
                    return closedAccountFound ? result : "No close account found.";
                }catch(e){

                }
            });
```

I am getting count in console.log(resCounter) 
but how can i return that or in other words how i can print that in handlebars ? 
Do i have to write another helper ?

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional "if statement" helper for Handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687099/conditional-if-statement-helper-for-handlebars-js)

Comment: @Will It doesn't solve my answers. i tried those.

Comment: I would recommend filtering your data _before_ passing it to your template function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a variable `closedAccountFound = false` and assign it true when you found any closed account then before returning the result check the value if `closedAccountFound` is true then return you result else return the message.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_Closed', function(list, opts) {
            var i, result = '', closedAccountFound = false;
            try {
                //console.log("List Closed length "+ list.length)
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                    if (list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed'){
                      //  console.log("List Closed  "+ list[i].OpenOrClosedDesc == 'Closed')
                        result = result + opts.fn(list[i]);
                        closedAccountFound = true; 
                    }
            return closedAccountFound ? result : "No close account found.";
        }catch(e){

        }
    });
```

Comment: can i have multiple if conditions within that for loop ??

Comment: yes, as many as you want, but it will be better if you break your code in multiple local functions

Comment: @cruiserKD how can i count the number of results ? 
Like i also want to display number of closed and open accounts.

Comment: @JSnewbie declare variables before for loop and in each if condition increment your variable